# Uing math floor to find average

Tags: c++

The middlemost position in an array of numbers may be calculated using the floor function, that is:

```
middlePosition = FLOOR ( (start position + end position) / 2)
```

Write a program that calculates the middle position from user inputs.

Note: Basically input 2 numbers and work out the average. Except we round down using the languages maths floor function: E.g.

```
middlePosition = [C++_math_library].floor((startPos + endPos) / 2)
```

Comment: What is the problem? You cannot find the floor function?

Answer (score 0):

With integer math, there is no need to use the floor function. In integer math, odd numbers will always be rounded down in every computer because it's how the Arithmetic Logic Unit works.  it is always advised to avoid using division when dividing by powers of 2 because division on x64 (It is now recomneded to drop support for x86 CPUs due to min spec being Core 2 Duo and Athlon 64.) uses hundreds of clock cycles and multiplication takes 3 clocks, but instead, you should use bit shifting to the right to divide and left the multiply by powers of 2. For each bit that you shift left or right, you multiply or divide by one power of 2 respectively. This also has the same effect as the floor function.

## Example

```
middlePosition = (start position + end position) >> 1; // >> 1 to / 2.
middlePosition = (start position + end position) >> 2; // >> 1 to / 4.
middlePosition = (start position + end position) << 2; // << 1 to * 4.
```

Notice how I put in the comment to the right `>> 1 to / 2`. The best practice to remind people of the purpose of why you are bit shifting because it's easy to inadvertently mess something up when you don't understand why something was done.